# Long running 2-3 minute asynchronous task that populates database

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am thinking of adding a button in app settings that starts a task to update SQLite database with data from API endpoint for offline use.

This task could take 2-3 minutes and a big problem would be if it gets interrupted by changing activities, etc.

How should I approach this? Is there a way to prevent user from switching activities or should I just display a message that database is updating and show a progress bar?

Comment: There's no way of preventing users from potentially closing your app, or shutting the device down. So, tracking the update progress, and using transactional queries would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: You should use IntentService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's never a way to stop the user from switching activities (although this should be done in a Service most likely).  Even if you could, you can't stop them from pulling the battery.  Always assume that a long running process could be killed asynchronously at any time, and program accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a service for long-running task. This way you can provide API for progress status, call back for completion etc.

- User click on Activity to start task -> launch service
- Activity now can get call back to update status bar
- If user navigate away and come
  back, new instance of Activity can display current task status.